# Hide apps in the Android market and only install from link

Tags: android

I'd like to publish an app in the market to make it easy to install, but we're in early beta, so I'd like to prevent random people from stumbling on it and likely giving it a bad review because they can't log in (or whatever).  Ideally, it would hide the app, unless you had a direct link to it.

Any way to do this?  It looks like you can prevent outside advertising, but I would assume the app would always show up in market searches.  You could set the maturity level super high, and try to lock down geography, but this all sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: AFAIK the only thing you can do is publish it with a garbled string as a name. That will limit its ability to show up in other peoples searches. However if you are willing to provide direct links to people for it, it would be nearly as easy if you just host your apk file on some other internet storage and give people a URL to the apk file. It would require the installer to turn on 'Allow non-market installs' in their settings. I have worked with some rather non-technical people but have always managed to get them to install it via a direct non-market link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go someway to 'hiding' the app, and dissassociate the beta from the full release:

- use a secret name, so the app won’t be ‘stumbled upon’
- use a separate market account
- don’t fill in the description
- give the app an expiry date
- give the beta a different package name from the real app - this will ensure low reviews don’t get carried over to post beta versions

Comment: I'll probably pick yours, as it has the best choices, although what we really want is a "pre-release" feature that retains the branding and package name.  Changing the package name is probably the best option, although its painful with R generation and whatnot.  Google needs a beta feature.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [HockeyApp](http://www.hockeyapp.net/). They provide a hosting service which allows you to make your builds easily accessible to invite-only testers, upload new versions automatically from your build scripts, and with a few small changes to your app you can get it to auto-update on users' devices.

On top of that you get nice error reporting.

I use it for distributing my beta builds, separately from the production-ready release builds which go on Google Play.

Comment: We're trying to get around sideloading issues. HockeyApp (or anybody else) still needs unknown sources and won't install on weird AT&T leftover devices. We've actually built our own product for beta testing, but haven't released it yet. Not sure that we will. https://touchtrack.co/ Client wants totally simple installs, so market seemed like the option.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update - the answer for most people will now be [Google Play's alpha/beta testing & staged rollouts](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en-GB).